# Computergenerierung von diversen grammatischen Formen von gegebenen Wörtern

Tags: inflection

Computerübersetzung von Sprachen ist heute sehr weit fortgeschritten. Da müsste m.E. doch in der Übersetzungssoftware Module vorhanden sein, welche die diversen grammatischen Formen eines gegebenen Wortes generiert, um die passende Form in der Zielsprache zu verwenden bzw. das richtige Wort in der Quellsprache zu erkennen. Gibt es Literatur über die genauere Logik (Algorithmus) von derartigen Modulen? Ich möchte nämlich aus einer gegebenen Liste von unterschiedlichen deutschen Wörtern eine zweite Liste generieren, in der alle grammatischen Formen der Wörter der ersten Liste enthalten sind.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a programming question, not about German specifically.

Comment: Was heißt "Mach die Recherchearbeit für mein Projekt für mich" auf Englisch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ein Beispiel für Verben ist Wiktionary. Einige Verbtabellen dort werden vollautomatisch generiert.

- https://de.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Flexion:leben&action=edit
- https://de.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Flexion:laufen&action=edit

Dort kannst du direkt in den Code reinschauen:

https://de.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Vorlage:Deutsch_Verb_schwach_untrennbar&action=edit